# use get_sites subsite_id with get_bloginfo"() and/or get_custom_logo

Tags: wordpress, multisite

I'm completely lost trying to combine functions.

I'm successfully using `get_sites` to produce a list of WP Multisite subsites.

I'm hoping to also pull `get_custom_logo` to display the logo,

and `get_bloginfo` for things like `$site_description = get_bloginfo( 'description' );`

I just don't know how to merge the gets. This is working:

```
/** get sites */
function make_list_shortcode() {
    $subsites = get_sites(
    [
        'public'  => 1,
        'number'  => 500,
        'orderby' => 'last_updated',
        'order'   => 'DESC',
    ]
    );
    if ( ! empty ( $subsites ) ) {
        $html = '<ul class="icon-bullets-greater">';
        foreach( $subsites as $subsite ) {
            $subsite_id = $subsite->blog_id;
            $subsite_name = get_blog_details( $subsite_id )->blogname;
            $subsite_link = get_blog_details( $subsite_id )->siteurl;
            $subsite_domain = get_blog_details( $subsite_id )->domain;
            $subsite_path = get_blog_details( $subsite_id )->path;
            $html .= '<li style="list-style: none!important;" class="site-' . 
            $subsite_id . '" ><a href="' . $subsite_link . '" target="_blank">' . 
            $subsite_name . '</a> at ' . $subsite_domain . '' . $subsite_path . ' </li>';
        }
        $html .= '</ul>';
        return $html;
    }
}
add_shortcode('list_sites', 'make_list_shortcode');
```

Comment: The solution is exactly the same as in the duplicate, you need `switch_to_blog()`

Comment: that example uses deprecated code that is not the same as get_sites...  it is not a duplicate question nor answered.

Comment: Ok, just change wp_get_sites for get_sites and you're good to go. Did you try?